# Why can't this code run, is it a bug in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, classnotfoundexception

I write a piece of code, then compile it with no errors. but when I run, it throws an exception (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TesKt$test$1$1).

Is this a language bug?

```
private fun test(block:()->Unit) = arrayOf(1).map {

    object {

        fun print() {
            println("Hello print")
            block()
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val array = test{println("Hello main")}
    array[0].print()
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting question. I struggled a lot and couldn't find the reason. But it seems if you don't use the `map`, it works well. Right now you have an array with only an element `1` inside and you map it to an array of anonymous objects. If you create the array of anonymous objects directly (`... = arrayOf(object {...})` ) then it compiles and runs.

Comment: To address the first part of the question: if the compiler stops with an error, then it has failed to compile the code.  So it won't have generated a class file.  And trying to run a non-existent class file gives a NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: @gidds I believe "on error" is a typo for "no error".

Comment: @Alexey Romanov, Yes ，I mistook the words for carelessness，thanks for your attention

Comment: @Mousa In my real work, the mapped object will use the value from the array, and the array size is larger than 1.  but for  simplify the problem, in this code,  the array only has 1 element

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to conclude that it's a bug in the Kotlin compiler. I played a lot with this code and looked into the compiled bytecode. It seems the compiler is losing some information about the anonymous class which is defined by `object`.

If we add a type to that object, then it works fine:

```
interface Printable {
    fun print()
}

private fun test(block:()->Unit): List<Printable> {
    return arrayOf(1).map {

        object: Printable {

            override fun print() {
                println("Hello print")
                block()
            }
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val array = test{println("Hello main")}
    array[0].print()
}
```

As you can see, I only defined a simple `Printable` interface and annotated the anonymous class with this interface.

Let's call your code: version `A`, and this code of mine: Version `B`.

I compiled code `A` and then decompiled it to `Java`. Here's the result:

```
import TestKt.test.1.1;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import kotlin.Metadata;
import kotlin.Unit;
import kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0;
import kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

@Metadata(
   mv = {1, 1, 15},
   bv = {1, 0, 3},
   k = 2,
   d1 = {"\u0000#\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u0011\n\u0002\u0010\u000e\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0010 \n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002*\u0001\b\u001a\u0019\u0010\u0000\u001a\u00020\u00012\f\u0010\u0002\u001a\b\u0012\u0004\u0012\u00020\u00040\u0003¢\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0005\u001a\u001c\u0010\u0006\u001a\b\u0012\u0004\u0012\u00020\b0\u00072\f\u0010\t\u001a\b\u0012\u0004\u0012\u00020\u00010\nH\u0002"},
   d2 = {"main", "", "args", "", "", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V", "test", "", "TestKt$test$1$1", "block", "Lkotlin/Function0;"}
)
public final class TestKt {
/*#19:*/private static final List<1> test(Function0<Unit> block) {
      Object[] $this$map$iv = new Integer[]{1};
      int $i$f$map = false;
      Collection destination$iv$iv = (Collection)(new ArrayList($this$map$iv.length));
      int $i$f$mapTo = false;
      Integer[] var6 = $this$map$iv;
      int var7 = $this$map$iv.length;

      for(int var8 = 0; var8 < var7; ++var8) {
         Object item$iv$iv = var6[var8];
         int it = ((Number)item$iv$iv).intValue();
         int var11 = false;
/*#31:*/ TestKt.test..inlined.map.lambda.1 var13 = new TestKt.test..inlined.map.lambda.1(block);
         destination$iv$iv.add(var13);
      }

      return (List)destination$iv$iv;
   }

   public static final void main(@NotNull String[] args) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(args, "args");
      List array = test((Function0)TestKt.main.array.1.INSTANCE);
/*#41:*/((1)array.get(0)).print();
   }
}
```

And this is the result of the same process for code `B`:

```
import TestKt.test..inlined.map.lambda.1;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import kotlin.Metadata;
import kotlin.Unit;
import kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0;
import kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

@Metadata(
   mv = {1, 1, 15},
   bv = {1, 0, 3},
   k = 2,
   d1 = {"\u0000\"\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u0011\n\u0002\u0010\u000e\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0010 \n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\u001a\u0019\u0010\u0000\u001a\u00020\u00012\f\u0010\u0002\u001a\b\u0012\u0004\u0012\u00020\u00040\u0003¢\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0005\u001a\u001c\u0010\u0006\u001a\b\u0012\u0004\u0012\u00020\b0\u00072\f\u0010\t\u001a\b\u0012\u0004\u0012\u00020\u00010\nH\u0002"},
   d2 = {"main", "", "args", "", "", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V", "test", "", "LPrintable;", "block", "Lkotlin/Function0;"}
)
public final class TestKt {
/*#19:*/private static final List<Printable> test(Function0<Unit> block) {
      Object[] $this$map$iv = new Integer[]{1};
      int $i$f$map = false;
      Collection destination$iv$iv = (Collection)(new ArrayList($this$map$iv.length));
      int $i$f$mapTo = false;
      Integer[] var6 = $this$map$iv;
      int var7 = $this$map$iv.length;

      for(int var8 = 0; var8 < var7; ++var8) {
         Object item$iv$iv = var6[var8];
         int it = ((Number)item$iv$iv).intValue();
         int var11 = false;
/*#31:*/ 1 var13 = new 1(block);
         destination$iv$iv.add(var13);
      }

      return (List)destination$iv$iv;
   }

   public static final void main(@NotNull String[] args) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(args, "args");
      List array = test((Function0)TestKt.main.array.1.INSTANCE);
/*#41:*/((Printable)array.get(0)).print();
   }
}
```

As you can see, the only differences are in the first line, as well as line numbers 19, 31 and 41 (commented like `#19:` and so on).

In code `A` a type (strangely) with the name of `1` is expected. But this type `1`, which is packaged as `TestKt.test.1.1`, is not found and so you got your error (`NoClassDefFoundError: TesKt$test$1$1`).

Inn code `B`, however, a more clear type of `Printable` is expected and found.

If the compiler had compiled the very first line of code `A` just like code `B` (`import TestKt.test..inlined.map.lambda.1;` instead of `import TestKt.test.1.1;`) then your code would have worked.

Comment: This is my conclusion as well. I found the bug was already tracked [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6007).

Comment: @Anton Oh, nice tracking! That's exactly it.